# Image from UICollectionView using renderInContext or drawViewHierarchyInRect both fail

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create an image from my collectionView.

That can be done with either **renderInContext** or with **drawViewHierarchyInRect**.

However....
When I use the renderInContext method, all selected elements in UISegmentedControls have no textLabel anymore....

Screenshot: 
[image]

And when I use the drawViewHierarchyInRect method, I get an all white image on the device (ios8 or above). (The simulator works fine).

This is my code:

```
func imageFromScreen() -> NSData {
    let savedContentOffset = self.collectionView!.contentOffset
    let savedFrame = self.collectionView!.frame
    self.collectionView!.frame.size = self.collectionView!.contentSize
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.collectionView!.contentSize, false, 1.0)

    self.collectionView!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()) // This method does not capture segmented controls correctly
    //self.collectionView!.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.collectionView!.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true) // White image on iOS8 & higher...

    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    // restore previous size and scroll position
    self.collectionView!.frame = savedFrame
    self.collectionView!.contentOffset = savedContentOffset

    return imageData!
}
```

What other options are available to generate an image from my collectionView?

Comment: Did you try UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.collectionView!.contentSize, true, 0.0), and  drawViewHierarchyInRect ?

Comment: That results in a black image instead of a white one....